# How to measure the similarity or the distance between human readable text files (license files)?

Tags: text-processing, diff, file-comparison

I want to find out which license a source tree has. The computer should make a suggestion which license files match closely. Then I would like to compare the texts with `meld` manually.

In a typical source tree, I have text files which could contain any kind of (license) text and would like to compare it with known license files in `/licenses/*`.

The metric should emphasize on the content of human readable text.

- low weight on single extra words
- low weight on typos
- minimal weight on whitespaces

How can I compare the file with Linux tools?

```
$> supertool unknown.txt /licenses/*  # example of an imaginary solution

0.10 gmap.txt
0.12 gnuplot.txt
0.14 GOG-EULA.txt
0.25 google-chrome.txt
0.13 Google-TOS.txt
0.87 GPL-1.txt
0.95 GPL-1+.txt
0.99 GPL-2.txt
0.56 GPL-2+.txt
0.60 GPL-3.txt
0.78 GPL-3+.txt
```

One idea, I had was to calculate the entropy of the licenses, then concatenate `unknown.txt` and the licenses and calculate the entropy again with `ent`. Files with minimal additional entropy are similar. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are specialized tools for this, you are looking for an *opensource license compliance* tool. Few examples of available tools:

- [licensechecker](https://github.com/boyter/lc)

Example output can look like this. Most of the tools will also scan the source files headers for license so you'll need to limit the scan to license files only.

```
Directory                       File            License            Confidence  Size
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/vtrefny/projects/blivet/  COPYING         GPL-2.0-or-later   99.47%      17.7K
/home/vtrefny/projects/blivet/  COPYING.LESSER  LGPL-2.1-or-later  99.63%      25.9K
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- [licensee](https://github.com/licensee/licensee)
- [licensecheck](https://github.com/google/licensecheck)
- [scancode](https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit)

and there are more, you should be able to find the right tool for your use. Some of these also provides libraries/API if you need something really specific.

Answer (score 2):

As the (possibly biased) maintainer of https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit I would say this is the best choice alright :D

In particular it has a different approach from most other tools listed here or otherwise available. It use multiple techniques and eventually it does a diff (like meld referenced by the OP) between your text and ~ 30,000 license texts and notices. The trick was to make it fast enough. Using a diff gives a better accuracy: it is now the industry leading tool for this space and used by most tools and orgs that are serious about open source license detection.